# Can iOS use Wi-Fi to get location even if Wi-Fi is off?

Tags: iphone, wifi, geolocation

On Android, if the user turns Wi-Fi off, the phone will still scan for nearby Wi-Fi access points to help determine the phone's location (discussed in e.g. [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/211186/how-to-disable-google-location-wi-fi-scanning-on-android/)). Does iOS also have this feature?

Comment: Probably not, but I couldn't say for certain.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If Wi-Fi is off, the radio is disabled, and it is no longer augmenting Location Services.

Often, you'll receive a message like the following to alert you to this:
[image: Location Accuracy]